# Curl gives segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, curl, raspberry-pi3, libcurl, raspbian

I am trying to download a .txt file from a server which I can access via the web browser on my raspberry pi.

Curl library gives segmentation error when I am trying to do this. Here is the code I am using.

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}


int checkNewFiles(){
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    string url = "http://52.233.176.151:1880/files/device/software/text.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/home/pi/Desktop/project/cpp/ab.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `write_data` does not look proper

Comment: `write_data` must have the correct prototype, or the code is undefined. You also need to ensure that the file was successfully opened. (BTW: you're just reproducing the default behaviour.)

Comment: I suspect that `FILENAME_MAX` is much larger than your raspberry can handle. Use `char outfilename[]` or `const char* outfilename`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, what is `url.c_str()` doing?

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

change this to

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
```

---

**Example : Curl program that download the text file.**

Offcourse you need to add this neccessary header file here.

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    const char *url = "http://localhost/yourfile.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\outfile.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); /* enable failure on http errors */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK) { /* check that the operation was successful */
          printf("curl_easy_perform(): %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the documentation:   "Pass in a pointer to the URL to work with. The parameter should be a char * to a zero terminated string which must be URL-encoded in the following format:"    std::string::c_str()  returns a const char*;  not a char*;  however; your code now has `char* url = <hard coded string>` which should at the very least give you warnings.

Comment: It solved the segmentation fault error but now the file has been downloaded as 0 byte. Althought It is succesfully downloaded when I paste the link to the browser.The file I've been trying to download is about 1.4 Mb

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're not checking for errors after `fopen`. If it fails, it returns a `NULL` pointer, which would cause a segfault when curl attempts to write to it.

I'm not convinced that `c_str()` was the culprit to your segfault in the original question as I have used that in numerous applications with no problems.